# Understanding an interview question about CSS

Tags: css, terminology, work

Currently, I'm applying for a position which is for a sort of mixed web designer and front-end developer position.
I've passed the CV screening and received an interview from from the company.

I got stuck mid-way because I didn't get the meaning of one of the questions. It says:

> Can you do direct editing of templates in CSS to create beautiful designs directly in web front end development? Please give a few examples for your work.

I think they're asking something normal, but English is not my first language and it's the first time I've applied for a designer job abroad, so I'm really not sure what exactly they're asking.

Could you give me a hint or an example for answering this question?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Theyre asking if you can edit css to style websites. Basically if you can do web design or edit existing web designs.

Your answer is "yes, i can edit existing styles (css) or write my own rules. To edit an existing style ill find the rule creating it by examining the code in a web browser and searching for that rule in the style sheet. I will then change the rule or write a new one below it. If i want to change the style in just that one place ill give it a new class name and create a new rule for that class, or put the element in a span with a unique class and write a rule for it. I dont prefer inline styles because i want to keep the code neat and it makes it easier to track problems in an external style sheet."

Basically make it sound like you're skilled and experienced at writing or editing css. Good luck.

Comment: This answer assumes the OP actually *has* those skills and doesn't mention at all the second part of the question, dealing with examples to show

Comment: The question also never asks for *how* to edit CSS, which your answer focuses on

Comment: I did nt see requests for samples before cai edited it, and the way i read the interview question is " can you edit css templates? Explain how". This is in an interview, theyre not asking for evidence. Op asked "can you give me a hint or an 3xample"? I answered in a way to help the asker by supplying them with verbal examples. Whether they should apply for this job or not was not asked, which your answer focuses on.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the perfect example, This is exactly what im doing on my work. Please let me quote some of your answers, thanks again.

Comment: @andre The company isn't expecting an answer like the one provided. This answer is incorrect

Answer (score 1):

They're asking if you can edit CSS (and likely HTML, perhaps a little JavaScript) to create designs in the web browser itself. This may include creating *all* of the CSS or editing an existing project. If you have these skills, you should answer "Yes" and then attach a ZIP or a link to websites of projects that you've created using HTML/CSS/JS.

But more importantly than that, if you cannot communicate with your coworkers using even the most basic terminology, such as the question you're being asked here, should you even be at the company that you're applying to? Communication is one of the most important parts of being on a team, so I don't think you're very ready to get that job because of that reason. At the *very* least, you should be very clear with the company about your limitations in English, conveying that it's a potential hard part of the relationship and (hopefully) that you're working hard in your extra time to learn better English.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I think that is not what i decide, they choose if they hire me or not including my English skills. I'm doing my best and i  don't think i should stop challenging. And this time I and the company aren't talking in person, if so I can ask from another angle about this question but i can't. but thanks again just in case I will put my urls and how to edit css for it.

Comment: @andre I agree that you should push your ability, but you should be honest with where you're currently at

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really an answer to the question...but was too long for a comment.

In general, I am told I tend to overshare personal information, so take my comment with a grain of salt.

If I were in the OP's position, I would provide a response to the best of my ability (using the interpretations suggested by commenters above).

However, I would also include something along these lines in my response: "I believe that my attached response answers your question, but I have to admit that I am still a bit unsure that I interpreted the question correctly. As an employee, when I face this type of situation, I will go back to the original questioner and ask for clarification, but that was not an option in this situation. So, if you review my response and it seems completely unrelated to the question, please allow me to get further clarification about what you would like to know, and I will be happy to respond again."

I think the OP is completely within his rights to pursue this position, even if his English isn't perfect.  But, the best way to turn a potential negative into a positive is not to try and cover it up and hope the employer doesn't notice, but to proactively address the issue up front.  He acknowledges that his English is not as good as a native speakers, but at the same time he reassures the employer that he himself is aware of the issue and that he already has a solution for it.

I was once fired from a job, ostensibly because I missed a particular deadline, but really because the office management had changed and the new person in charge didn't like me, and took this as an opportunity to fire me.

On interviews for a new position, I would always try to address this firing before the interviewer even asked why I had left the other company.  I explained that I had been put into a position where I was guaranteed to fail at one of my responsibilities--either missing the deadline, or letting a team go out to an interview without proper preparation, and I made a judgement call.  I explained that my direct supervisor and I had discussed it afterwards and had figured out how we could avoid a similar situation in the future, and then I explained that the deadline was important enough to upper level management that someone had to be a scapegoat, and I ended up being that person.

I went on four interviews before accepting a new job, and each of the people that interviewed me gave me really positive feedback about my being forthcoming with this information.